# Sorting an array of dates

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, asp.net-4.0

I have created an array from a CSV of date values and now need to be able to sort them so that I can then get the latest date from the array.

I have tried:

```
Array.Sort()
```

but this doesn't sort correctly, I suppose because the array values are strings, any body got any ideas??

Thanks for any help.

**CODE USED TO CREATE ARRAY**

```
'array string exampel: "19/07/2012,23/07/2012,23/07/2012,19/07/2012,25/07/2012"
Dim ArrDates As Array = ArrDates .Split(",")
```

**SOLUTION**

```
Dim ArrAgentsReportCheck As Array = AgentsReportCheck.Split(",")

Dim ArrDates As New List(Of Date)
For i As Integer = 0 To ArrAgentsReportCheck.Length - 1
    ArrDates.Add(ArrAgentsReportCheck(i))
Next

ArrDates.Sort()
Dim LatestDate As Date = ArrDates.Max()
```

Comment: Create a List (not Array) of DateTime objects (not strings). You can use DateTime.TryParse/TryParseExact to convert the strings to DateTimes, and then use the Sort Method.

Comment: Show us an exemplary string that you want to convert to date.

Comment: Code used  to load the array and the format of the strings (to be interpreted as dates) should be very helpful here

Comment: thanks for replies, added in example of dates string and how its converted to array.

Comment: As others have said make a `List(of DateTime)` instead and then you can use `Max()` on it to get the largest value (ie latest date). If getting the latest date is all you want then you don't need to sort the whole list so Max will be quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the help i've added the solution above, although i couldn't accept a comment as the solution so accepted Shaikh Farooques answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As astander said, It is very complicated to sort a array having datetime values. Instead just convert the array to List or ArrayList and make your life easy.

For ArrayList you can use the following syntax:

```
List<DateTime> dates = ... // init and fill
dates.Sort();
dates.Reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, i've added my final solution above in case that can help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrDates = ArrDates.OrderBy(Function(d) DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray()
```

Alternately, you can use `OrderByDescending()` depending upon your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert strings to DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact

Another way just to [write your own IComparer and pass to Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bzw8611x.aspx)